# Android 10 not showing carpenter () emoji in TextView, Even though I used Android X Emoji lib

Tags: android, emoji

My testing device Android 10 (Nokia 6.1 plus) doesn't render a carpenter () emoji. It is showing fine in the Samsung devices. I did try few libraries like:

- Android X Emoji Compact - https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/emoji#1.1.0
- vanniktech/Emoji - https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji#google

I am not sure what is the issue with only this emoji. It shows a not-supported kind of emoji rectangle. Please check out the screenshot here:

[image]

Not sure, If I am doing anything wrong here.

Comment: It does not show it in this page in Chrome browser of Android 10 device either. Read your post.

Comment: Sorry @blackapps, not following you